# Getting Shell Window Command

Tags: c#

I am trying to get input command from shell Window (not res). Below is the scenario.
I am trying to get this info using C#, but if it is not possible with C#, any other language like C/C++ will also work.

1. User enter some command in Shell Window.
   Command like dr/cd/mkdir etc
   Shell window like Command prompt/ PowerShell
2. Whenever user press enter, capture the command which he executed and log it.
3. I need a consistent approach which work on all shell window. There can be more shell windows apart from cmd and powershell.

What I have tried:

1. I tried using keyboard press. Using Keyboard press, I am able to capture key detail but user can use some shortcut keys. so this will not work
2. Trying to get data from Window title. This work for Command prompt but not with powershell.
3. Tried Window API like "getWindowText" but it is giving window Title. I suppose ,there are thousand of WinAPI. If anyone can narrow down the give some suggestion on WinAPI methods. That will also work

Please help !!

Comment: For console applications you would hook into stdin/out/err.  There is no mechanism to categorise/identify what a "Shell" window is, you would need to decide that for yourself.

Comment: Programs like ConEmu tend to just capture the console's buffer at regular intervals. That's probably the only option you'd have to do that reliably.